# javascript not working in chrome-app

Tags: google-chrome-app

I'm trying to get started writing chrome apps.  For some reason when I view as a chrome app the javascript does not work but it works fine as a webpage.  Here's the simplest instance of my issue.

opening index.html with chrome works as expected--the "hello world" string becomes "CLICK" when the button is pressed.  Running as a chrome app nothing happens when the button is pressed.

manifest.json:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "My first app",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "app": {
    "background": {
      "scripts": ["main.js"]
    }
  }
}
```

main.js

```
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() {
  chrome.app.window.create('index.html', {
    bounds: {
      width: 800,
      height: 609
    }
  });
});
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>test</title>
</head>

<body> 
    <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">click me</button>
    <script>
        function myFunction(){
            document.getElementById("testdiv").innerHTML = "CLICK"
            }
    </script>
    <div id="testdiv">hello world</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

well, [Chrome Extensions Content-Security-Policy](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy.html) doesn't allow usage of **inline scripts**.

> Inline JavaScript will not be executed. This restriction bans both
>   inline  blocks and inline event handlers (e.g. ).

try to include a script file containing your javascript in your page (`<script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script">`) instead of using your javascript code within the page.

hope that helps.

Comment: Apparently even things like onclick="myFunction()" count as inline JS.  So, I needed to add the button listener from my script as well.

Comment: There is also an error message printed to the console about inline scripts not allowed. The console should become your best friend when developing Chrome apps. You should also differentiate between possible multiple consoles for a single app: one for the background page and one per every open app window. All of these will show up in Developer Mode under your app in `chrome://extensions`. They can also be accessed via the context menu in any window of the app, unless the menu is overridden by the app.