# How to call javascript function without button click?

Tags: javascript

I have seen some pages in which we can input in textarea and correspondingly an output gets displayed for it
no button clicks in between , see an example here http://ntools.infoexpo.in/p/html-to-xml-encoder_4042.html

How to apply this type in the below code?
html:

```
<textarea  id="source"  placeholder="Text Entry."></textarea>
<p id="result"> </p>
```

**Javascript**

```
function myFunction()
{
var str = document.getElementById('source').value;

var len = str.length;
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="<textarea>"+len+"</textarea>";

}
```

Comment: See my example and you will understand how it works :)

Comment: @crypticous how to make it working for Chrome App

Comment: Posted script working in Chrome too, its cross browser

Comment: script works, but how to customize it in order to apply this script in code of a google chrome app - im writing ; google chrome app rules has some restrictions on javascript inclusion ; see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20727493/javascript-not-working-in-chrome-app

Comment: I answered what your question demanded, I am not aware of google chrome extensions, that you have to find out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest you to use `addEvent`,`removeEvent` function approaches due to cross browser issues.

`addEvent` function is capable of to add events on elements, while `removeEvent` remove them

```
if ( document.addEventListener ) { // if addEventListener provided
    this.addEvent = function(elem, type, fn) {
        elem.addEventListener(type, fn, false);
        return fn;
    };

    this.removeEvent = function(elem, type, fn) {
        elem.removeEventListener(type, fn, false);
    };
} else if ( document.attachEvent ) { // if attachEvent provided
    this.addEvent = function(elem, type, fn) {
        var bound = function() {
            return fn.apply(elem, arguments);
        };
        elem.attachEvent("on" + type, bound);
        return bound;
    };

    this.removeEvent = function (elem, type, fn) {
        elem.detachEvent("on" + type, fn);
    };
}
```

For example if you have **HTML**

```
<textarea  id="source"  placeholder="Text Entry."></textarea>
<textarea  id="result"  placeholder="Text Entry." disabled="disabled"></textarea>
```

**JavaScript**

```
addEvent(document.getElementById("source"),"keydown",function(){ // event will occur on keyup
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = this.value; // this refers to textarea element
});
```

<kbd>[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wyTnw/4/)</kbd>

**PS.** *Check out* <kbd>[attachEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536343%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)</kbd> and <kbd>[addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener)</kbd> methods

Comment: `onkeyup` or `onkeydown` would be sufficient.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to call in on load of your page try this

```
<body onLoad="yourFunctionName();">
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use the onchange event, so everytime the user made some change on the text field it will trigger the function.

HTML will be something like this

```
<textarea id="source" onchange="myFunction();" placeholder="Text Entry."></textarea>
<p id="result"> </p>
```

JavaScript code

```
function myFunction() {
    var str = document.getElementById('source').value;

    var len = str.length;
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML="<textarea>"+len+"</textarea>";

}
```

Comment: It's bad practice that you are recommending such an approach, even though OP wants to get rid of it

Answer (score 0):

use onchange event:

```
object.onchange=function(){SomeJavaScriptCode};
```

Answer (score 0):

`<textarea cols="40" onchange="do_encode(this)" onkeyup="do_encode(this)" ...>`

Every time user type/paste anything will trigger [onchange](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/Reference/Events/change) and [onkeyup](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/Reference/Events/keyup) event.

There's a full list of [events reference on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events).

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('source').onchange(function() {
     // Write your code here . It will execute when your changes the text in textarea

})
```

go through the link
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp

Comment: Bad practice, also textarea doesn't support onchange event

Comment: @crypticous how it works here http://ntools.infoexpo.in/p/html-to-xml-encoder_4042.html